# Changing onclick handler for an element after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

```
   div.onclick = function(data, dom) {
        return function() {
           if (data.seenAlready == true) { // HACK
              $(this).children().toggle();
              return;
           }
           recursiveSearch(data, dom);

          // after this onclick, I want to assign it to a toggle like function. no clue how to do it.
       }
  }(child, mycontainer.appendChild(div));
```

I'm trying to swap the onclick method after first onclick on a dom element. I've just not had any success, it seems to some sort of closure loss, or something. I'm fine using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this and both ways are by using a `jQuery` function:

1) Use `one` API method - this will work just once. You will click it once and then you choose your own second handler and the first one will not fire again e.g.

```
$(myselector).one(function(){
    $(this).click(myotherhandler);
});
```

Here is the link to this API http://api.jquery.com/one/.

2) You can choose the following way to replace the event handler .

```
$(myselector).click(function(){
    $(this).off();
    $(this).click("secondhandler");
});
```

this will turn the first handler off and will just fire second handler

Check this jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/fekuq/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ok, I think I may know the problem. the event is firing multiple times screwing up my state. I'll try this jquery one. How do i use Jquery if I already have a reference to my dom element?

Comment: Can you elaborate your questions please.What do you mean by already having reference to your Dom element. I  guess you need this `$(DomReference)`